# append if element in list

Tags: append

I'm trying to create a parser for program. For example,
I entered (what I want)

> "(2+3)-4" it will become something like this "(minus, (plus, num 2, num 3),num 4)"

What I've done so far..

> "(2+3)-4" I then split it and it becomes list Z = ["(","2","+","3",")","-","4"] then I compared if "-" is a member of Z, if true I append the element "-" into a new list ["-"]

I'm not sure if the way I'm doing is correct, I'm new to Er-lang and struggling quite a lot. If anyone is able to offer me some insight, thanks.

Comment: The answer depends on the full grammar for your little language. If the grammar consists entirely of what you show, which means only binary plus and minus operations, integers, and grouping via parentheses, you might get away with using regular expression operations to parse it. But if there's more to the language, you're probably better off writing an actual parser. Are you showing us the full grammar?

Comment: I was never told of using the full grammar such as abstract syntax tree. I guess regular expression is allow but I'm not sure how I'm going to go about adding the rest of them, it would be inconsistent to use more cases...

Comment: I'm not asking about abstract syntax trees, but rather the rules of your grammar and syntax. For example, is `2+3-4` allowed? Are any operators in addition to `+` and `-` allowed? Are values always integers? Etc.

Comment: BTW, given the `re:split/3` call you show, the resulting list will be `["(2","+","3)","-","4"]`. You'd need to add both the open and close parenthesis characters to your split pattern so they're separated from adjacent numbers.

Comment: well these are the only ones i wanna test for now, if i can do one then the others are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following, which returns a tuple-based representation of its input:

```
parse(Expr) ->
    Elems = re:split(Expr, "([-+)(])", [{return,list}]),
    parse(lists:filter(fun(E) -> E /= [] end, Elems), []).
parse([], [Result]) ->
    Result;
parse([], [V2,{op,Op},V1|Tacc]) ->
    parse([], [{Op,V1,V2}|Tacc]);
parse(["("|Tail], Acc) ->
    parse(Tail, [open|Acc]);
parse([")"|Tail], [Op,open|TAcc]) ->
    parse(Tail, [Op|TAcc]);
parse(["+"|Tail], Acc) ->
    parse(Tail, [{op,plus}|Acc]);
parse(["-"|Tail], Acc) ->
    parse(Tail, [{op,minus}|Acc]);
parse([V2|Tail], [{op,Op},V1|Tacc]) ->
    parse(Tail, [{Op,V1,{num,list_to_integer(V2)}}|Tacc]);
parse([Val|Tail], Acc) ->
    parse(Tail, [{num,list_to_integer(Val)}|Acc]).
```

The first function, `parse/1`, splits the expression along the `+` and `-` operators and parentheses, preserving these in the resulting list. It then filters that list to remove empty elements, and passes it with an empty accumulator to `parse/2`.

The `parse/2` function has eight clauses, described below:

- The first two handle the case when the parsed input list has been exhausted. The second of these handles the case where multiple elements in the accumulator need to be collapsed into a single tuple consisting of operator and operands.
- The next two handle clauses parentheses. When we see an open parenthesis, we push an atom `open` into the accumulator. Upon seeing the matching close parenthesis, we expect to see an operation tuple and the atom `open` in the accumulator, and we replace them with just the tuple.
- Clauses 5 and 6 handle `+` and `-` respectively. Each just pushes a `{op,Operator}` tuple into the accumulator, where `Operator` is either the atom `plus` or the atom `minus`.
- The final two clauses handle values. The first one handles the case where the accumulator holds a value and an `op` tuple, which gets replaced with a full operation tuple consisting of the atom `plus` or `minus` followed by two `num` tuples each holding integer operands. The last clause just handles plain values.

Putting this in a module `p`, compiling it, and running it in an Erlang shell yields the following:

```
1> p:parse("2+3").
{plus,{num,2},{num,3}}
2> p:parse("(2+3)-4").
{minus,{plus,{num,2},{num,3}},{num,4}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your anser and great explanation. I will thoroughly analyse it carefully for my understanding.

Comment: can you explain this part "parse(lists:filter(fun(E) -> E /= [] end, Elems), [])." what do you mean by empty elements?

Comment: If you execute `re:split("(2+3)-4", "([-+)(])", [{return,list}]).` in an Erlang shell, the result is `[[],"(","2","+","3",")",[],"-","4"]`. You can see there are two empty elements `[]` in that result, caused by the regular expression grouping. The call to `lists:filter/2` just drops those empty elements so the parser doesn't need to deal with them.